# Error: Failed to lookup view "users/register" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My app can not find a page from the `views` directory. I think I've setup the configuration correctly and other files are working fine in `views` but this one is not working.

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "users/register" in views directory "D:\NODE PROJECTS\MyBlog\views"
    at Function.render (D:\NODE PROJECTS\MyBlog\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\NODE PROJECTS\MyBlog\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1017:7)
    at file:///D:/NODE%20PROJECTS/MyBlog/src/routes/UserRouter.js:18:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\NODE PROJECTS\MyBlog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\NODE PROJECTS\MyBlog\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)     
    at Route.dispatch (D:\NODE PROJECTS\MyBlog\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
```

This is my path setup

```
app.engine('ejs', engine)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views'))
```

And a call from router

```
UserRoter.get('/register', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('users/register', {title: 'Sign Up'})
})
```

And this is the structure of views directory

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in the third line of code, instead of:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views'))
```

Should be:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/templates/views'))
```

---

I mirrored your project (folder and file structure) and everything seems to be fine:-)

**Folder & file** *structure* :

[image]

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/templates/views"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", { title: "Keep Calm and Do not stop coding!" });
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("users/register", { title: "Sign Up" });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is  listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**register.ejs**

```
<title><%= title %></title>
<h1>Register page works fine!</h1>
```

**output**:

[image]

*Tested with "ejs": "^3.1.6", "express": "^4.17.2", node 16.13.0*